# Icon is "transparent" bootstrap

Tags: html, css, svg, icons

I'm editing my navigation menu but my shopping cart icon isn't showing...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
    <title>Hilgenberg Store</title>
</head>

<body style="min-width: 372px;">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-danger border-bottom shadow-sm mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><strong>Hilgenberg Store</strong></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Principal</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Política de Privacidade</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="align-self-end">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Quero me cadastrar</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Entrar</a>
                    </li>
                    **<li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                            <svg class="bi testIcone">
                                <use xlink:href="/bi.svg#card3" style="fill: white;"></use>
                            </svg>
                        </a>
                    </li>**
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to use the external link to add a shopping cart icon to the site's navigation menu.
I tried to change its color through `main.css` but I didn't get any changes. The icon is there, but it's transparent or something like that: [image: Screenshot of Webapp]

Comment: Main question here would be, wether `/bi.svg` successfully loads, and actually contains an element with ID `card3`. We can't tell either from what you have shown us so far.